# Is SQL injection or any other attack possible while copying data from table to another table

Tags: sql, database, security, sql-injection

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB. TableA contains unreliable data and user can enter what ever data they want into this table. I want to copy the data from TableA to TableB using:

```
Insert into tableB(col1,col2) 
select col1,col2 
from TableA 
where find_in_set('someStaticText',replace(col3,';',',')
```

Is it possible for SQL injection or any other attack to happen while copying this data from TableA?

I have tried the standard SQL injection examples but it doesn't seem to be a problem and since my SQL query is static " insert into tableB select from tableA" I don't see any problem either.

But since we are dealing with completely unreliable data from TableA, is there anyway to be sure that there will not be any issue while copying the data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection attack is when a user-submitted string (or rather, any input that is not created in your code, which you yourself guarantee to be safe) is injected into an executable SQL code before it is sent to the database.

The classic example is immortalised in [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/); user input `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --` is presumably injected into something like `INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('$name')`, creating the following series of statements:

```
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Robert');
DROP TABLE Students;
--');
```

Note that if the statement was written correctly, either as a prepared statement (`INSERT INTO Students VALUES (?)`) or if the string was first correctly escaped (which would transform `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --` into `Robert''); DROP TABLE Students; --`), it would have been inserted correctly; once it is in the database, it is just data, with no special superpowers.

Crucially, the dangerous bit is where the SQL statement text is created, in your application code, not in the database. Since your SQL statement is a static string, nothing can be injected, and there can be no SQL injection attack.

Comment: "a user-submitted string" is a **fallacy** there is NO reliable measure to tell whether a string is "user-submitted" or not. So it should be just any input.

Comment: Anyone coming to this question with a different problem, where copying is done using some programming language instead of SQL, most likely will conclude that, given the data is coming from SQL, and not from "a user", it should be safe. Effectively opening their app towards second order injection. This dangerous stuff, "a user supplied input" should be eliminated from this generalized advise.

Comment: Yes, I meant any input that is not inherent in code.